# Use regular expressions on scrapy selectors

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping data from [this google page](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20reviews%202nd%20chance%20treatment%2040th%20street&rlz=1C1JZAP_enUS697US697&oq=google%20reviews%202nd%20chance%20treatment%2040th%20street&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6183j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x872b7179b68e33d5:0x24b5517d86a95f89,1):

To get the reviews I don't have any issue since all are in a class called: "review-full-text" then I'm just using this xpath to get them:

```
review.xpath('//*[@class="review-full-text"]//text()').extract()
```

But need to get the responses as well, and in this case, the name of the class is not consistent, e.g. for the first review the response is in the class:

```
LfKETd r-id3h0OaXd7RA
```

But for the second one the class name is:

```
LfKETd r-iGpfKJm1EL2o
```

Which has the first part of the name fixed "LfKETd r-" the rest change for each response. Is it possible to use a regular expression inside the xpath like: "LfKETd r-.*" or any other way to match the class name for each response?

Comment: Sadly, an awful lot of XPath implementations -- especially free ones -- haven't upgraded to XPath 2.0 (let alone 3.0 or 3.1) and therefore have no support for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you should use.

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'LfKETd r-')]
```

By using this always you are checking the first part of the class and not to worry about the dynamic part.

Answer (score 1):

Although [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/), used by Scrapy (through Parsel), does not support regular expressions natively, [Parsel](http://parsel.readthedocs.io/) adds two extensions to XPath 1.0, and one of them [adds support for regular expressions](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions).

Specifically, it introduces the `re:test` function, which works similarly to the native `contains` function, but specifying a [Python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) instead of a substring as the second parameter.